# How are ratio keylines (as mentioned in Google's Material Design) applied to a calculation?

Tags: android, material-design

Simply, how do you use the ratio keyline as mentioned in Google's Material Design in a calculation?

For example, setting the `peekHeight` of a `BottomSheet` in android to [`PEEK_HEIGHT_AUTO`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetBehavior.html#PEEK_HEIGHT_AUTO) *configure(s) the sheet to peek automatically at 16:9 ratio keyline*.<sup>[[1](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetBehavior.html#setPeekHeight(int))]</sup>

I assume that a `peekHeight` is calculated internally and that value is used.
**Using the 16:9 ratio, as well as the screen width and height (and maybe the density?), how is this value derived?**

I am currently reading through the [Material Design documentation](https://material.io/design/layout/spacing-methods.html) but there doesn't seem to be anything describing how these ratio keylines are applied to a calculation. I'm looking for some formulas but there doesn't seem to be any. Or maybe my understanding of ratio keylines are wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the ratio keyline are applied as follows:

In my example, to calculate the `peekHeight`, first the space above the `peekHeight` seems to be calculated like so:

```
topMargin = (9.0f * screenWidth) / 16.0f;
```

Then, the `peekHeight` is calculated as the difference between the screen height and the the space like so:

```
peekHeight = screenHeight - topMargin;
```

As can be seen above, the ratio keyline, 16:9 is used in calculating the space above the element. Because the ratio keyline is mentioned in the [Spacing](https://material.io/design/layout/spacing-methods.html#spacing) section of the Material Design documentation, I think its main concern is with the space the element leaves.

Also, one thing to note is that the ratio seems to have been reversed when calculating for the space. I can't seem to describe it properly, but visually it's like this: (I can't use a screenshot from the app I'm currently developing so the image may seem off)

[image]

(I plan to revisit this post once I completely understand what ratio keylines are)